# Python 3.8: definition with if/else condition and return/yield (always returns a generator)

Tags: python, if-statement, return, yield, python-3.8

[**Python 3.8 | Spyder**]

I was trying to introduce a simple definition that would either `return [1,2,3]` or `yield` the numbers sequentially.

The minimum working code is as follows:

```
def example(condition):
    if condition:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
    else:
        return [1,2,3]
```

If one attempts to use the `def`, **it will always return a generator**. Even if the `return` appears first in the if/else pair:

```
def example(condition):
    if not condition:
        return [1,2,3]

    else:
        yield 1
        yield 2
        yield 3
```

It seems python is not ignoring the presence of the yields even if `condition = False`.
This is an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: If there is any `yield` present in the function it will become a generator. It does not need to be "hit".

Comment: But that limits it brutally. It means that the if/else is not respected at all and if it is not respected, does it not constitute at least a security flaw?

Comment: @David: I'm not sure how you made that leap (to security flaw) - the code in the alternate branch isn't being executed in any way, it's just that the compilation phase uses it to decide the function is a generator. The behaviour is well known. A function that yields from any code path is a generator. If you return something, I *think* that actually causes a `StopIteration` exception with the return value as the value.

Comment: The security leap was my worry about the compilation process taking into account whatever is inside the if/else pair, without caring if the part that will be executed will be what is inside the if or the else. In the meantime, I found the temporary, extremely sad solution:

Comment: ```
def ret():
    return [1,2,3]
def yie():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
def retyie(yielder):
    if yielder:
        return yie()
    else:
        return ret()
```

Comment: Why do you need it to do this way btw? Couldn't you just say `list(example())` if you didn't want it as a generator?

Comment: Sometimes you need one result at a time :) not all at once. For example, when you need to decide what to do based on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the generator in the form of a generator expression:

```py
>>> def example(condition):
...     if condition:
...         return (i for i in (1, 2, 3))
...     else:
...         return [1, 2, 3]
```

```
>>> example(1)
<generator object example.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x000000000257BBA0>

>>> example(0)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or you can define the generator separately:

```py
>>> def g():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...     yield 3
...
>>> def example(condition):
...     if condition:
...         return g()
...     else:
...         return [1, 2, 3]
```

```
>>> example(1)
<generator object g at 0x000000000257BBA0>

>>> example(0)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'll have to accept this sad solution (python's fault). It makes us repeat code unecessarly.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, a `def` statement with a `yield` statement in its suite defines a generator. It is inconsequential, and in fact undecidable, whether the `yield` is actually reached at runtime.

```py
def another_example():  # this function has a well-defined type
    if random.random() < 0.5:
       yield 'What is the type of this function?'
    return 'Of course it is a generator function!'
```

---

In order for a function to evaluate to either a generator or a non-generator value, use a separate definition for the generator or a generator-expression.

```py
def example_generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

def example(condition):
    if not condition:
        return [1,2,3]
    else:
        return example_generator()
```

If both paths ultimately should provide the same values, it is semantically identically to make the choice outside of the function. This makes it sufficient to provide just a generator function; the result can be converted to another type externally.

```py
def example():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

print("I prefer lists, such as:", list(example()))
```